# Should I display Edit/Delete Buttons when only one field is editable?

Tags: interface, input-fields, user-expectation

I know there's a lot of questions out there asking where to place the edit/delete buttons in a row. My question is if there is only one field of data that is editable in a row, does it make sense to place the edit button at the end of the row?

Let me explain with examples,

Below is a table in its normal state with information about people. In my case, only the fields with **Blue** text is editable. You can't edit the name or e-mail. Only their role. Also note this role is not something users can type - they have to select between : Actor, Singer and Comedian.

[image: Rows]

So I thought of two possible methods. Method A is the more traditional approach. Placing an Edit/Delete button at the end. But does it make sense if only one field is editable? 
Method B will show a dropdown box on hover over the editable field.

[image: Methods to show editable fields]

My questions -

1. Is Method A applicable here?
2. Are there any problems with using Method B?
3. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method B is  far most efficient**

You should always display the "edit" function the nearer as possible of the concerned field. Especially in your case where you have only one field editable

The delete function can be placed at the end of the row because it act on the complete row.

Both of these must be displayed when you roll-over the row not only the field, to inform the user about the available options